# LinkedIn Share URL Button from Website Not Showing Message Body

Tags: linkedin-api, share

I am trying to add a share button from my website to Linkedin. It works fine. I am using this template

```
<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=@Model&source=@Model" target="_blank">
    <img src="https://simplesharebuttons.com/images/somacro/linkedin.png" alt="LinkedIn" />
</a>
```

The issue is that I get this screen:

[image]

When the user clicks on send to individuals the link is not included in the message body. How to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

LinkedIn ***only*** supports the `url` parameter in its share URL.

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url={url}
```

Source: **[Microsoft LinkedIn Share URL Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/share-plugin)**.

If you are interested in a regularly maintained GitHub project that keeps track of this so you don't have to, check it out!  [Social Share URLs](https://github.com/bradvin/social-share-urls)

[image: Social Share URLs Image]